# Getting most recent objects in a list

Tags: java, list

How can i get the most recent objects in a List?
I have tried

```
int i = 5;
while(i > 0) {
    Object o = list.get(list.size() - i);
    i--;
}
```

but to no avail, i could be doing it wrong, but if i am i am unware how to fix my mistake :/
(The problem is it is still giving me the entire list)

Comment: what do you mean by most recent, the last element added? The list structure has no way to tell what was added last. If you want the last element in the list that's just `list.get(list.size() -1);`

Comment: I edited your code example to be more readable and added a closing brace from the `while` - feel free to edit if this isn't correct.

Comment: yes the last element added. `list.get(list.size() -1)` didnt work when i tried it. And thank you Paul for that. :)

Comment: What are you doing with Object o once you get it? just discarding it? And how do you know that this code "doesn't work"? Very unclear question.

Comment: Do you want to *remove* the element from the list, or just get a reference to it (like you're doing now)?

Comment: Please clarify certain things. For example, what type is `list`? What exactly "isn't working?"

Comment: im going to use it later, at the moment its nothing, just saving it for later.

Comment: This makes no sense -- "saving it for later". You are *not* saving it in the code above; you are discarding it. Again, please clarify things.

Comment: @jskiles1 its List<Object> and when i do `list.get(list.size() - 1);` for some reason it still returns the entire list, which is strange.

Comment: Robby, *nothing* is returned in the above code.

Comment: when i say im saving it for later i mean i haven't actually done anything with it yet.

Comment: Since you declared the `Object o` inside the while loop it only has visibility in that loop. If you want to use it you have to in that loop. If you want to use it outside of the loop you have to declare it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could just reverse the list then iterate over it:

```
// Your original list
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); // Populated elsewhere

// Make a copy, so you don't corrupt the original list
List<Object> reverseList = new ArrayList<Object>(list);
// Reverse the order of its elements
Collections.reverse(reverseList);
// Now iteration will be in "latest added first" order - ie LIFO
for (Object o : reverseList) {
    // Do something with o
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're expecting your code to change the original list, but this is a wrong assumption since the code simply gets an object held by the list and doesn't remove it. Then you discard the object held by o, so there is no way to test if your method is working or not. To solve this, you've got to save the stuff produced from your method to test if it works or not.

```
int i = 5;
List savedJunk = new ArrayList();
while(i > 0) {
    Object o = list.get(list.size() - i);
    savedJunk.add(o);
    i--;
}

for (Object foo : savedJunk) {
   System.out.println(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question and you pretty much had the right answer. The central idea is that items in a list appear in the order in which you added them, so to get the most recent item you need to go through the list in reverse. Here is one way to do that with a for loop.

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("one");
myList.add("two");
myList.add("three");
myList.add("four");
for (int index = myList.size() - 1; index >= 0 ; index--) {
   System.out.println(myList.get(index));
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
four
three
two
one
```